# .Net dependency injection how to avoid new inside a service class

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have a general question about dependency injection in .NET Core (I am using .NET 8).

I already have some experience in a .NET Blazor server application and I know the difference between

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
services.AddScoped< IMyService, MyService>();
services.AddSingleton< IMyService, MyService >();
```

The three lines above have an effect on how many instances of the `MyService` class are instantiated.

(a new instance for every client call, or just one per new user, or just one for all users and clients).

All well and good so far, but now my question: let's say in the `MyService` class I need to instantiate one or more objects of another class (`MyUserClass`) depending on different input parameters. For example, in a loop. So I would do

```
myUserObj = new MyUserClass();
```

But I have read that with DI we should never use "new".

But how can I instantiate `MyUserClass` class depending on different parameters with DI inside `MyService` class?

And the second problem is how to inject the `ILogger` in `MyUserClass` when I call

```
myUserObj = new MyUserClass();
```

I guess I missed some basics and I would really appreciate if someone can help me on this question.

Thanks and best regards
JP

Comment: Not sure I'm following entirely, but Dependency Injection isn't about *never* instantiating anything manually. If you are doing something in a loop where you for instance are generating a list of users based on something happening, that can never happen with DI. 

Regarding logging, usually the classes you do instantiate manually, are things that don't need other things (like a logger) injected.

Comment: _"But I have read that with DI we should never use "new"."_ - Where? I am pretty sure, it wasn't meant the way you think it was.

Comment: Lacking in details and seems very general - not clear if MyUserClass is a real class or just a made up example, or what the "depending on different input parameters" means, or why it is thought that new() should be avoided here (other than "i've heard I should do this"). Also - two questions here not one.

Comment: @topsail I didn't say there is no room for improvement but I for one 1. cut newbies some slack, 2. prefer suggestions for improvement over dv. That said, OP will surely improve based on your observations ;)

Comment: Honestly, I think the correct here is "no, you wouldn't use DI for this". So ... not a lot to answer. My opinion. I wouldn't reach for a factory if the only reason to do so was to say "now I'm using DI". Perhaps I should add my answer - "Don't"? Seems like a blunt answer and without detail also a bad one. Again - hard to suggest real improvement with no actual code.

Comment: @topsail Fair enough. I based my ... let's call it "guess" on the statement that OP needs to inject a Logger ... which indicates some sort of Service-ish class to me. The Factory is also only _one_ way to solve this; with more details we could of course find a better suit or increase confidence in the answer. Until we get that, that's what I can offer to MagicJP. I also added a disclaimer that goes in your direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am not 100% convinced this applies to you**, but it *sounds* like you want a Factory:

```
// Given, there is a class MyUserClass

public interface IMyUserClassFactory
{
    MyUserClass Create( string dependendProp );
}

public class MyUserClassFactory : IMyUserClassFactory
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public MyUserClassFactory ( ILoggerFactory loggerFactory )
    {
         _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public MyUserClass Create( string dependendProp )
        => new MyUserClass( dependendProp, _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyUserClass>() );
}
```

then you can register the Factory with DI, have it injected and create instances like so:

```
var myUserInstance = _factory.Create( "different parameters" );
```

---

**But** - as already stated in comments - just because you are using DI, does not mean you cannot, must not or will not ever use `new` anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. I know a real example would be better. But I should scale down my real project, otherwise it's too big for stackoverflow.
From your posts I learnt that creating a new instance with "new" under DI is not wrong.
I have seen the factory examples, but there was also a "new" and I see in your example that you do it with "new" as well. My mistake was that I thought that with DI new should never be used again. So that is wrong.

Comment: I didn't know ILoggerFactory either. I will try to implement this in my project. All your posts and examples help me a lot. Many thanks to all contributions